# Changing a string makes whole script not work in Titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

So I have a script which creates a simple table view, but changing a simple string seems to have drastic consequences.

This works (I have stripped it to the relevant parts):

```
data = [];
db = Ti.Database.install('../data.sqlite', 'person');
rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM person');
while (rows.isValidRow()) {
  data.push({
    title: rows.fieldByName('first_name'),
    hasChild: true,
    c_id: rows.fieldByName('C_ID')
  });
  rows.next();
}
tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
  data: data
});
...
win.add(tableview);
...
```

But changing `title: rows.fieldByName('first_name'),` to `title: rows.fieldByName('first_name') + rows.fieldByName('last_name'),` throws an error of 
`Result of expression 'win.add' [] is not a function. at persons.js (line 32)` (line 32 is `win.add(tableview)`.

The only difference is that line but it makes the whole script fail.

Thanks in advance
Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was because I'm using coffeescript which wraps the code in a function wrapper, which causes problems (somehow). Removing the function wrapper fixed it but now I can't use coffeescript any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a blank space between them?

`title: rows.fieldByName('first_name') + ' ' + rows.fieldByName('first_name')`

and if you take another table from the table? like last_name or so, does it crash then too?

Comment: Argh. I meant to make it `rows.fieldByName('first_name')`, but I forgot to change it here. Yes, adding a space as you suggested still crashes it with the same error.

Comment: you should alert data and see what type of data its making.

Comment: Are you sure that the fields are written correctly from the database? That it isn't typed differently or so? And you can indeed type some alerts to see where it crashes, or some some `Titanium.API.info ` to see what values there are wrong

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I found the problem, it was because I'm using coffeescript which wraps the code in a function wrapper, which causes problems (somehow). Removing the function wrapper fixed it but now I can't use coffeescript any more.